# How do i get data from different tables using JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have 2 tables e.g.

```
public class Block
  {
public int ID{ set; get; }
public string Name{ set; get; }
public string Price { set; get; }
}

public class Room
{
public int ID{ set; get; }
public string Name{ set; get; }
public string Price { set; get; }
}
```

From these tables how would i select price from different table? E.g. When a user selects a Name (from Block class) and Name (from Room class). Each Name has its own Price, IF a user selects BlockA that has a price of $22 (from Block class) and SeatingRoom that has a price of $25(from Room class) Javascript should add them and display the addition in different web-page: 
This [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/WY3A4/) outlines what i need but instead having values in drop down menu how do I retrieve it from the database, so that onClick Search button it will display the calculation. This is my Ajax method that gets the place name and populates into a dropdown menu.

```
        function Method() {
        ajReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var opts = '';
                $.each(data.d, function (i) {
                    opts += '<li>' + '<a class="">' + this.Name+ '</a>' + '</li>';

                });
                $('.Dropdown').html(opts);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my onclick button:

```
        $(document).on("click", "#buttonClick", function () {
  });
```

My webmethod for Ajax:

```
        [WebMethod]
    public IEnumerable<Room> Method()
    {
        List<Room> r= data.getRoom();
        return r;
    }
data is my class name and getRoom is a method
    public List<ToBooking> getRoom()
    {
        List<Room> t= new List<Room>();
        SqlConnection myConnection = new etc..);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", myConnection);

        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
                            b.Name= reader["Name"].ToString();
        }

    }


         <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="blockss" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span id="headingFrom">From:</span><span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu Dropdown">
                <li><a class=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What server side language are you using?  You have to write the web services to hit your database and transfer you json object.

Comment: i am using C♯ for database connection .asmx pages for [WebMethod] and Ajax calls to perform a action.

Comment: what does data.getRoom() do?

Comment: data is my class name and getRoom is my method which uses SQL query to get the list of Name's. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Java as the server-side language, but you've including nothing about how the back end actually works. The simplest answer is that you need to follow this pattern:

1. Write a REST function in Java to handle a particular type of AJAX call like a database lookup.
2. Call that REST function with jQuery providing the right parameters.
3. Have the jQuery callback insert the data correctly into the DOM however you want.

If I were implementing this, I'd use Apache CXF for the REST. CXF is generally the easiest thing I've seen for beginners to write a clean service layer in Java these days for something like this.

Comment: I am using C♯ [WebMethod], i have updated my question. I am using aql server management studio to create my database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample webmethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = System.Web.Services.WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Demo : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public class Block
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Price { set; get; }
    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public List<Block> GetBlockList()
    {
        List<Block> result = new List<Block>();
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Sql Connection String Here"))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT id, name, price FROM tableName WHERE block = @block";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        string ex = e.ToString(); // Do something with the error
                    }
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                result.Add(new Block(){
                    ID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString()),
                    Name = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                    Price = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And now the AJAX to generate a dropdown list along with the event handler for the dropdown to display the price when the selection changes:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Services/GetBlockList",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        failure: function () { alert("failure"); },
        error: function () { alert("error"); },
        success: function (response) {
            var row = response.d;
            var html = "<select id=\"BlockList\">";
            html += "<option value=\"0\">Select</option>";
            $.each(row, function (index, item) {
                html += "<option value=\"" + item.Price + "\">";
                html += item.Name;
                html += "</option>";
            });
            html += "</select>";
            $("#htmlBody").append(html);
        }
    });
    $("#BlockList").change(function () {
        alert("Price: " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

This is the basics of it.  You can, of course, do a lot more with AJAX than just generating a dropdown, but this should get you started.

Comment: In here your appending both price and name. I dont want price to be shown in dropdown menu. price should be calculated onclick button. AND in #BlockList how do i add two prices?

Comment: Did you try this example?  The price is in the option's value field, which is not displayed.  The only thing that will be displayed is the item.Name.  You can get the values from multiple drop-down boxes and add them together with JavaScript/jQuery.  $("#item1").val() + $("#item2").val()